# How to test OnClick in Appium Android Test

Tags: appium, appium-android

I am new to `Appium`. I try to test the `OnClick` function of a button. 
The Activity includes a Button and a `TextView`. When I click the Button, the text of the `TextView` changes (only 1 time - not toggle).
However, the `OnClick` funtion does not work. This is my Test:

```
@Test
public void click_button() {
  AndroidElement text = (AndroidElement)((AndroidDriver)driver).findElementById(package_ + "text");
  AndroidElement button = (AndroidElement)((AndroidDriver)driver).findElementById(package_ + "button");
  String prevTest = text.getText();
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(button));

  //attemp 1
  button.click();
  driver.findElement(MobileBy.className("android.widget.Button")).click();

  //attempt 2
  Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
  actions.click(button);
  actions.perform();

  //attempt 3
  AndroidTouchAction touch = new AndroidTouchAction ((PerformsTouchActions) driver);
  touch.tap (TapOptions.tapOptions ()
          .withElement (ElementOption.element (button)))
          .perform ();
  String postTest = text.getText();
  assertNotEquals(prevTest, postTest);
}
```

This is my OnClick Function:

```
public void buttonClick(View view) {
    textView.setText("Clicked");
}
```

In addition, this is the setUp function:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    File classpathRoot = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    File app = new File(classpathRoot, "build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Galaxy A7");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "8.0");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app);
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "UiAutomator2");
    driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    package_ = "com.example.trafalgarandre.testtesting:id/";
}
```

This is server logs for approach 1[part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcHI0.png)[part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1H0d.png)[part 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88sDo.png)[part 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQCJd.png)[part 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJ7Qm.png)[part 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Utgfq.png)[part 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbiZN.png)

The test case fails due to the content of `TextView` doesn't change.
[screenshot of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lt2sm.png)
How do I fix this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you initialize DesiredCapabilities? Is your appium server running? What is the error you are getting? Add the error log too

Comment: It runs normally. Just that the test fails due to the text of TextView doesn't change

Comment: Can you share the `errors` you see in server logs while executing different attempt codes ?

Comment: Please add the appium server log too.

Comment: @AmitJain I dont see any Error tag in the server logs but I will just share it. However, may I ask how can I share the `errors` here?

Comment: I think you need to define your driver as static. Try defining your driver as static.

Comment: @SubanDhyako I tried to define as static but it still fails

Answer (score 0):

The `text` you refer to get `postTest` text will always return the same text as before since you didn't find the text view again after the text gets updated.

To make sure you get the updated text the next time you must re-find the same element again and then do `getText` on it.

Try this and check. It should work.